# Ubuntu 20.04 USB failed SecureBoot

Tags: ubuntu, secure-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 11. However when I select the USB to boot, it shows "Operating System Loader signature found in SecureBoot exclusion database("dbx"). All bootable devices failed Secure Boot verification."

Comment: Why are you trying to install an Ubuntu release older than the hardware? A newer LTS release is available: 22.04.